# Changes to pixel aspect ratio in photoshop does not show in other programs

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've got a freeze frame image from a video that i've been editing. The image originally looked squished, so i changed the pixel aspect ratio from **Square** to **D1/DV PAL Widescreen 1.46**, and it looks fine.

However if i open this file in any other program, for example Prieview, it seems to not have made any difference? I'm still getting that squished look. And i can't send it to my client like that.

Is there any way i can save this file so that it keeps the desired pixel aspect ratio? Different file types don't seem to work, i've tried .tiff .pdf .psd but to no avail.

See examples below:

Unedited Photo:

[image]

Edited Photo:

[image]

Edited photo opened in Preview:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you change the actual width of the photograph instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the aspect ratio doesn't alter the image, it only tells Photoshop how to interpret the image's pixels.  (Note how the ruler in your "Unedited" and "Edited" images shows the same pixel dimensions).

You need to alter the image, stretching the pixels horizontally, to achieve the look you want.

Comment: That did it! Seems so obvious now. Thanks @digijim. But is there any way to ensure that you get the aspect ratio spot on? The original image size is 1440x1080. I changed it to 1440x800, looks roughly alright but not certain if its exactly correct?

Comment: Since true 1080 HD video has an aspect ratio of 16:9, you'd want to leave the image at it's current height of 1080 pixels, and stretch your image to a width of 1920 pixels.  Or, if you really want to keep the width at 1440, then you'd want a height of 810 pixels.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one alternate..open the new document file in photoshop keep the size same as your edited photo & then drag your edited photo in this new document file & then check the preview..hopefully it will not get squished now :)